# object lifecycle in List<T>.add(T _element) in C#

Tags: c#, list, addition

I know the add function actually only adds a reference of object _element. My question is, if my list is a global one, by I use add function in a function, so the _element is local as well. Is it true that even after I exit from thst function, the _element that was declared is still on the heap until say when the global List is dead?

Thanks.

Comment: As a side note: a "global list" is almost always a bad idea, and if you **do** have such, you need to be really careful to synchronize access to it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the *object* pointed too by the reference will now stay alive. More generally, objects almost always outlive the code that creates them, since regular GC is *non-deterministic*.

Answer (score 0):

This is partially true. The element will stay on the heap as long as their are references (except for weak references) towards it. If the list is "dead" as you state it or the element is removed. The element will be removed from the heap, but not right away.

Even when there are no references refering to the element anymore, we still have to wait for a garbage collection to clean it up. There is a chance that the element moved to a higher generation within the Garbage collector, and therefore even a first level garbage collection wont remove the element from he heap.

Garbage Collection (in .NET) is heavy stuff, i suggest you read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx for more information

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all the while objects are held in that list, memory they hold will not be reclaimed by GC. If you wish to have GC collect objects in static or long living collection, you may be interested to look at [WeakReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx).